# laravel how to show one to many data in view (fetch ) in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

hello I'm trying to fetch one to many data in view like post with this feast comment shooed be show in view

iam able to get value in array now i what to show in view

**my array controller**

```
public function data($id)
{
     
 $post= User::with(['Comments'=>function($query){ 
    $query->first(); 
}])->find($id);

 dd($post->toArray());
```

}

**array data**

```
array:53 [▼
  "id" => 39
  "name" => "KUMAR"
  "post" => "hello word "
  "created_at" => "2022-02-11T02:38:51.000000Z"
  "updated_at" => "2022-02-11T10:05:26.000000Z"
  "comments" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:13 [▼
      "id" => 6
      "user_id" => "39"
      "comment" => "good post"
      "created_at" => "2022-02-11T15:13:51.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2022-02-11T15:13:51.000000Z"
    ]
  ]
]
```

**my view Controller**

```
public function data($id)
{
     
 $post= User::with(['Comments'=>function($query){ 
    $query->first(); 
}])->find($id);

 return view('user.post',compact('post'));
```

}

Comment: The code looks okay. In your `user/post.blade.php`, you have `$post` variable defined. You just have to use it like `{{$post->name}}`, etc.

Comment: @ruleboy21 yes i tried but it not working in view data not dispelled, it was empty in array i getting data

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @ruleboy21 no im not get error but getting user table data only in view

Comment: You need to add the code for the view as well. Maybe you're not doing something right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your `User` model already has this `comments` relationship

```php
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
```

You can add this `firstComment` relatioship

```php
    public function firstComment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Comment::class)->oldest(); // or ->latest()
    }
```

Then fetch your `User` this way

```php
$post = User::with(['firstComment'])->find($id);

dump($post);
dd($post->firstComment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function data($id)
{
     
 $post= User::wherehas('Comments', function($query){ 
    $query->where('user_id',$id); 
})->get();

 return view('user.post',compact('post'));
}
```

Comment: Undefined variable: id